# Problems with responsive mobile rotation

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm making the mobile version of this website www.simoneschiavo.it/occomputer

I have applied a media-queries.css to format the original css using:

- @media screen and (max-width: 770px) FOR LANDSCAPE VERSION
- @media screen and (max-width: 400px) FOR PORTAIT VERSION

If u load the page just in portait or in landscape (without rotation) it works fine in each page.
So? ok, it works good as I want in each version, but when I rotate and came back it's a mess!

Seems like when I rotate, it takes something about portait and something also about landscape as index of width and mix it. ALSO sometimes realoading page it disappear and everything is white, waiting too for loading.

I've already use this format for my personal website www.simoneschiavo.it: you can rotate 1000 times and every time it takes the right media screen. Help me out :)

Comment: Look a this link to css tricks. It tells you what media queries to use when targeting ipad landscape and portrait. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Have I to put every format? or just someone?

Comment: Just use the ones that you need. Seems like you just need ipad (landscape and potrait). So, just copy and paste the ipad versions and put your styles in between the brackets.

Comment: Still have the smae problem. I put styles of "@media screen and (max-width: 770px) " on that one but the problem is already there..

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using this script:

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> // RELOADS WEBPAGE WHEN MOBILE ORIENTATION CHANGES  
    window.onorientationchange = function() { 
        var orientation = window.orientation; 
            switch(orientation) { 
                case 0: window.location.reload(); 
                break; 
                case 90: window.location.reload(); 
                break; 
                case -90: window.location.reload(); 
                break; 
            } 
    };
</script>
```

so every time u rotate, it reload the page in 1 sec, but it's no good as it could be. Still waiting for help. Thank you

Comment: IS the website in your first post using this script? I don't see any reload delay, only orange bar jumping due to 'contatti' `a href` tag going to the next line pushing down element below.

Comment: "IS the website in your first post using this script?"
Sorry but i don't understand what are you meaning :)